# Vertically align two objects after rotation

Tags: html, css

I have two objects (or elements?, I'm new to CSS) and I want to vertically align them. The problem is that, one of them has been rotated, so it vertically aligns the original object instead of the rotated object.

```
div.sectionwrapper{
/* I'm assuming I need to put something here*/
}

div.left-section{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 500px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

div.right-section{
    height: 500px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: `vertical-align` only works when you have `display: table;` or `display: table-cell` set.

Comment: Oh, is there another way to vertically align, or do I need to use one of those?

Comment: "vertical-align only works when you have display: table; or display: table-cell set." That is inaccurate. Vertical-align can be applied to any inline element.

Comment: When you say original and rotated object are you referring to the same object, just post rotation?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that wasn't very clear.